# Vue Firebase / Firestore Duplicates

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to go through a tutorial (link below) to learn vue and firebase. There is a main dashboard page with a list of components, and I have gotten that to display a list of employees. Then there is a view employee component. When I started to build that, and just loaded data, I started getting this error:

> Uncaught FirebaseError {code: "app/duplicate-app", message: "Firebase:
>   Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app).",
>   name: "[DEFAULT]", stack: "[DEFAULT]: Firebase: Firebase App named
>   '[DEFAULT]…0)↵    at fn (http://localhost:8081/app.js:89:20)"}

The firebase code I added to view employee is as follows:

```js
import db from "./firebaseInit.js";
export default {
  name: "view-employee",
  data() {
    return {
      employee_id: null,
      name: null,
      dept: null,
      position: null
    };
  },
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    db
      .collection("employees")
      .where("employee_id", "==", to.params.employee_id),
      get().then(querySnapShot => {
        querySnapShot.forEach(doc => {
          next(vm => {
            vm.employee_id = doc.data().employee_id
            vm.name = doc.data().name
            vm.dept = doc.data().dept
            vm.position = doc.data().position

          })
        });
      });
  }
};
```

When I comment out this script on the view employee page, the error goes away. From what I can tell, I have done everything the same as the tutorial in the video, and as my buddy who did the same project.

There is also a warning, which may be related, which states as follows:

> There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing. This
>   can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with
>   other case-semantic. Use equal casing. Compare these module
>   identifiers: *
>   /Users/jdurell/code/employeemanager/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!/Users/jdurell/code/employeemanager/src/components/FirebaseInit.js

I am working on this tutorial / project:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjEzK4me1k8&index=4&list=PLillGF-RfqbYsOOycB67Raf9dwmL6Y31M

Comment: Just added. Thanks!

Comment: you should use everywhere your module import with the correct casing: `import db from "./FirebaseInit.js";` my guess is that you named this import using a different casing in your other component which results to load this file twice which leads to the double app error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nemesv had the correct answer. It was a casing issue. I had the issue FirebaseInit on the other component. I changed that to firebaseInit so it was the same case on both components, and the error resolved. Thanks!

Comment: In that case I'm voting to close the question as a typo, since it's unlikely that somebody else in the same situation will benefit from it.

Comment: I lost a few hours trying different things to fix it. I think the premise that spelling with different cases creates different firebase instances is useful to know.